# How to check multiple values in negative expression with optional binding?

Tags: swift, optional-binding

I want to check if two optional variables are all null. For example, in C,

```
int n1 = 1;
int n2 = 2;
if( n1!=0 && n2!=0 ) {
     //  do something.
}
```

Is there any way to do this in Swift?

Comment: I don't see a `nil` in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `&&` operator:

```
// here are the optional variables:
var a: Int? = nil
var b: Int? = nil

if a == nil && b == nil {
    // this will only run if both a and b are nil
}
```

Comment: I'd like to find when two optionals are all nil.

Answer (score 1):

What you call *optional binding* is actually just *if statement* with multiple conditions. *Optional binding* is used when you want to define constant/variable from constant/variable which can be `nil`. When isn't, code inside if statement gets executed.

But you need to define two values with optional type. This you can do with question mark `Type?` and then you can check if both values aren't `nil`.

Your code in Swift:

```
let n1: Int? = 1
let n2: Int? = 2
if n1 == nil && n2 == nil {
    //  do something.
}
```

Comment: Can I write in one line inside if statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if two optionals are `nil` by comparaing them to `nil`

```
let n1: Int? = nil
let n2: Int? = nil
if n1 == nil, n2 == nil {
    print("Nil all the way")
}
```

Separating conditions with a comma is equivalent to using `&&`.

Here is an alternative using tuples:

```
if (n1, n2) == (nil, nil) {
    print("Nil all the way")
}
```